I can't access my GKE cluster in google-cloud-shell
enter image description here

i click connection button
copy [gcloud container clusters get-credentials autopilot-cluster-1 --region asia-northeast3 --project loyal-copilot-422015]

enter image description here
3. happened this error message

hi there, one of your image is in Korean language, you better change the language to English then repost it here, as the community's main language is English! and you get assistance pretty fast~

Did you choose public or private cluster?

Please add more information to the post. Nevertheless it might be that the cluster is private and that you should add the CIDR of the CloudShell session you are using to the authorized networks of the cluster.
